# Where is running terminal program scrollback located

Tags: terminal

I had multiple terminal programs running at same time and Terminal stopped responding.

Now I wonder if there is any chance to get those session output/scrollback files and save them.

Comment: Which version of Mac OS X are you running?

Comment: I'm running OS X version 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so with Snow Leopard. Unless someone knows a backroots way of getting it, and the HDD is journal formatted. I know that Lion does a good job of restoring sessions in its native applications, or at least keeping them logged. I am afraid though that you may be out of luck on that one.